# Perform an action two different RxJS observers get 1 result

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two different observers, and upon geting the first result for each I perform an action:

Observer 1

```js
specialties$.subscribe(
            (value) => {
                this.specialtiesOptions = value['result'].map((specialty) => {
                    return {...specialty, selected: false}
                })
            }
        )
```

Observer 2:

```js
partner$.subscribe({
    next: (value: Partner) => {
        // other stuff happening here
        this.partner = mutate(value)
    }
```

I have another method, which is related to both, which should only be called when I get the `value` for both observers, and both `this.specialties` and `this.partner` are correctly populated.

How can I do this?

Is it possible to do this while keeping the operations logically separated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this. Not sure if it's the cleanest or most idiomatic solution... but it works for me so far. Leaving in case it helps someone else (and so I can tell it sucks if it does!)

I create a couple `Subjects`:

```js
const partnerIsDone$ = new Subject<boolean>()
const specialtiesAreDone$ = new Subject<boolean>()
```

which I update on each `subscribe()` call:

```js
specialties$.subscribe(
            (value) => {
                this.specialtiesOptions = value['result'].map((specialty) => {
                    return {...specialty, selected: false}
                })
               specialtiesAreDone$.next(true)
            }
        )

partner$.subscribe({
    next: (value: Partner) => {
        // other stuff happening here
        this.partner = mutate(value)

        partnerIsDone$.next(true)
    }
```

And then subscribe to each `Subject`, and check if the properties are set:

```js
const maybeApplySelectedSpecialties = () => {
                    if (this.specialtiesOptions && this.partner) {
                        this.selectPartnerSpecialties()
                    }
                };

partnerIsDone$.subscribe(() => maybeApplySelectedSpecialties());
specialtiesAreDone$.subscribe(() => maybeApplySelectedSpecialties());
```

It works. What I don't like is that I'm checking the status of the properties. In this specific case it works, but I'd prefer to check for example if both subjects are `complete()`, but not sure how would I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of dealing with observables is through chaining them.

It might seem like a burden at first when everything is wrapped on an `Observable<Something>` instead of having just `Something`, but on the long run it's great when you have to do asynchronous stuff.

What if `this.specialtiesOptions` wasn't a value, but an observable? You could define it as

```
this.specialitesOptions$ = specialties$.pipe(
  map(specialties =>
    specialties.result.map((specialty) => ({
      ...specialty,
      selected: false
    })
  )
)
```

Note how we haven't subscribed to anything yet. This just defines that `specialtiesOptions$` is an observable which is going to do some computation over `specialties$`. You can do the same for partner:

```
this.partner$ = partner$.pipe(
  map(partner => mutate(partner))
)
```

And now when you need to do something, you can consume the observable and it will work:

```
combineLatest([
  this.specialtiesOptions$,
  this.partner$
]).subscribe((specialtiesOptions, partner) => {
  this.selectPartnerSpecialties(specialtiesOptions, partner)
})
```

The idea though is that you can keep chaining observables as you need them, and you `.subscribe()` as little as possible. This way of programming is harder though, you need a big mental shift from imperative to reactive, but for complex scenarios it pays off.

Things to keep in mind:

- If you're expecting asynchronous values to just load once, you can convert them to promises (using `firstValueFrom` from RxJS) and it might make some things a bit simpler. But using observables allows you to react to changes, which is needed in many cases.
- Use `shareReplay(1)` or `share({ ...config })` when you don't want to repeat sending requests or recalculating every value. Observables are unicast, which means that every observer will have their own instance of the observable. share operators make them shared
- You can make `this.specialitesOptions$` as complex as you need... This version only loads the initial value and then it's done, but you could add in logic for when the values get changed (I guess based on user input, etc). If you do that, then any other observable depending on `specialtiesOptions` will receive the new value and recalculate whatever it needs to.

Comment: Thanks! But on my code, `this.specialtyOptions` and `this.partner` need to hold actual values, which are consumed elsewhere. With this example, these are not being set to anything, right?

Comment: @Angulator1st no, that's the tradeoff. It makes it harder to work with, but at the same time you have the guarantee that no one will access either of these variables before they haven't been loaded (because they also would have to consume the observable-version of them, which will resolve when they have a value)